# See css properties on hover of a class with Intellij

Tags: css, intellij-idea, plugins, visual-studio-code, intellij-plugin

I've just discovered [Css-Peek](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pranaygp.vscode-css-peek) for VSCode, but as I'm using Webstorm, I would like to know if someone knows an equivalent, or how to do this directly in Webstorm.

Basically, this plugin allows to see in the IDE the CSS properties applied to a class or a tag, just by putting the cursor over it in the HTML template.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ctrl+click` (or whatever shortcut is assigned to **Navigate | Declaration** main menu action) allows jumping to selector definition in a stylesheet, similar to **Go To** in VSCode

`Ctrl+Shift+I` (**View | Quick Definition**) shows the definition in a tooltip:

[image]

Editing CSS inline is not yet supported, please vote for [WEB-10320](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-10320) to be notified on any progress with this feature

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was searching. I was sure something like this would exist in IntelliJ, just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Mac the shortcut is ⌥Space (option + space) or ⌘Y